# Perform a row lookup in where clause?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I get all articles that have a category, I have a sub query to specify this category:

```
Article::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($categorySlug) {
    $q->where('slug', $categorySlug);
})->get();
```

Each category has a parent category, I need to find out the parent category from the slug and use the parent category in the sub query, something like:

```
Article::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($categorySlug) {
    $cat = Category::where('slug', $categorySlug)->first();
    $q->where('category_id', $cat->parent_id);
})->get();
```

But is there a more efficient way to do it? How can I perform the parent_id lookup in the where clause?

Answer (score -1):

I see you want to get articles data from category table with slug search, so you can join the tables to get the result

```
 $articles = Article::join('category', 'article.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
                   ->where('category.slug','=', $categorySlug)
                   ->get();
```

Comment: This does not take into account the parent id

Comment: @panthro i don't understand what do you mean with "This does not take into account the parent id". can you give me an example about what do you want your end result in json / array ? so i can help you better